# Use custom name for imported module in ReasonML

Tags: import, module, ocaml, reason

In Python I can use `import somemodule as foo` in order to use custom names for external modules in your scripts.

How can this be done in ReasonML, for example if I want to import `ReasonReact` as `React`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Module aliases are handy for this:

```js
module React = ReasonReact;
```

This differs subtly from `import` in that it will not just bind the module to a new name for internal use, but also export it unless you restrict what's exported with an interface file (or a module signature if used in a submodule).

[Documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec249)